# Powershell editing android strings resource xml file

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

i'm tring to edit the android xml string resource file with powershell.
My goal is to put the name of the string inside the value of the corresponding entry:

from this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<plurals name="test1">
<item quantity="one">%d hello</item>
<item quantity="other">%d work</item>
</plurals>
<string name="test2">house</string>
<string name="test3">horse</string>
</resources>
```

to

```
<resources>
    <plurals name="test1">
    <item quantity="one">test1</item>
    <item quantity="other">test1</item>
    </plurals>
    <string name="test2">test2</string>
    <string name="test3">test3</string>
</resources>
```

I think is possible, but I'm not powershell expert. Starting from scratch I have done in this way.. Are there a better way ?:

```
param()

$fileName = "string.xml"
  
$repoFile = $fileName

"Script start!"

if(!(Test-Path $repoFile)) {
    "warning: $repoFile was not found!"
    continue
}

$root = [xml](Get-Content $repoFile)
  
"Plurals"

foreach ($plural in $root.resources.plurals) {
  foreach ($node in $plural.item){
    $node.InnerText= [string]$plural.name
  } 
}

"Strings"

foreach ($node in $root.resources.string) {
  $node.InnerText= [string]$node.name
}

$root.Save($fileName)
```

Comment: Have you tried... anything?

Comment: I'm trying, i'm studing how to parse an xml with powershell !

Comment: can we see those attempts?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I have done in this way but I don't know if there are a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xpath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) selector to achieve this task

```
$root = [xml](Get-Content $repoFile)
# replace text for item node under plurals under resources
$root.selectNodes("/resources/plurals/item") | %{ $_.InnerText = "test1" }
# replace text for string with attribute name = test2 under ressources
$root.selectNodes("/resources/string[@name='test2']") | %{ $_.InnerText = "test2" }
# replace text for string with attribute name = test3 under ressources
$root.selectNodes("/resources/string[@name='test3']") | %{ $_.InnerText = "test3" }
```